# Javafx bufferedreader only reads first line

Tags: java, javafx

I have written a method for my login page to check the user in a text file where the usernames and passwords are preserved. What the program does is only read the first line and ignore the rest. How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for the help!

the method:

```
              try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file path)))
            {

                String currentLine = br.readLine ();


                while ((currentLine) != null) {

                    String[] s = currentLine.split(":");

                    if (loginView.getTfUsername().getText().equals((s)[0]) && loginView.getPfPassword().getText().equals(s[1])) {
                        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        alert.setHeaderText("Welcome, " + loginView.getTfUsername().getText () + (" ! U bent aangemeld"));
                        System.out.println(loginView.getTfUsername().getText()+" success "+loginView.getPfPassword().getText());
                        alert.showAndWait();


                    }
                    else  {

                        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                        alert.setHeaderText("Invalid username or password!");
                        System.out.println(loginView.getTfUsername().getText()+" fail "+loginView.getPfPassword().getText());
                        alert.showAndWait();

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: you never update currentLine - do something like `while ((currentLine =br.readLine) != null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read all lines before deciding whether the password is valid or not.

`break;` exits a loop and will prevent more iterations, so you'll read a single line at most.

You should do something like this:

```
String password = ...
String username = ...
boolean match = false;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file path))) {
     String line;
     while (!match && ((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
          String[] s = line.split(":");
          if (username.equals(s[0]) && username.equals(s[1])) {
              match = true;
          }
     }
}

if (match) {
    // handle successful login
} else {
    // error message
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, the program is partly working now, it checks all the lines in my text file before logging in successfully. For example I have 2 users: if I want to login with the second one it will give me a error message at first and after that it logs in successfully. I think it has something to do with my loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: @YouKnowWhoThisISxo What fabian has written would work fine with all the cases. Show alter according to the `match` value. Handle success/ error handling out side the loop as @fabian does.